# EF Core throwing "'this' type cannot be an interface itself."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble with EF Core 3.1. with code that worked up until recently. I have this method that is called before SaveChanges is called on DbContext:

```
private void SetProps<TEntity>(TEntity dbEntity, EntityState newState)
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    var entry = this.dbContext.Entry(dbEntity);
    ...
    if (dbEntity is IDbEntityBase dbEntityBase)
    {
        var baseEntry = this.dbContext.Entry(dbEntityBase);
        if (newState == EntityState.Added)
        {
            baseEntry.Property(t => t.Id).CurrentValue = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of code is left out for easier reading, so any design changes would be hard to do.

The problem I'm having is in the call to `baseEntry.Property(t => t.Id).CurrentValue = Guid.NewGuid();`. When that code is called, EF is throwing an exception `'this' type cannot be an interface itself.`.

IDbEntity is some base interface that all entity classes implement (it has some common properties).

EF call stack looks like this:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'this' type cannot be an interface itself.
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.VerifyInterfaceIsImplemented(RuntimeTypeHandle interfaceHandle)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetInterfaceMap(Type ifaceType)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeInterfaceMap(TypeInfo typeInfo, Type interfaceType)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ExpressionExtensions.GetPropertyAccess(LambdaExpression propertyAccessExpression)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1.Property[TProperty](Expression`1 propertyExpression)
  at InDocEdge.Sap.Database.EfContext.SapDbContext.ProcessBeforeSaveChangesData() in C:\MyCode\MyDbContext.cs:line 2
  at InDocEdge.Sap.Database.EfContext.SapDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\MyCode\MyDbContext.cs:line 1
```

The code worked until recently, but somehow now EF is not happy (as I understand) that I provide interface type for Entry method, which I think is possible.

Does anybody know what could be wrong or how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just no such thing as an EntityEntry for an Interface type.  It needs to be an Entity Type. And `EntityEntry<TEntity>.Property` needs to find the Entity Type Property, not the Interface Property (they are conceptually and possibly actually different).

But in the normal case, your Entity's property implementing `IDbEntityBase.Id` will also be called `Id`, and you can just pass that name to `entry.Property(string)`, eg:

```
private void SetProps<TEntity>(TEntity dbEntity, EntityState newState) where TEntity : class, new()
{
    var entry = Entry(dbEntity);

    if (dbEntity is IDbEntityBase)
    {
        if (newState == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Property(nameof(IDbEntityBase.Id)).CurrentValue = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

Or, since you're only setting the `EntityEntry.CurrentValue`, you can set it directly through the Entity object, through an IDbEntityBase reference, instead of the EntityEntry.  EG:

```
    private void SetProps<TEntity>(TEntity dbEntity, EntityState newState) where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        if (dbEntity is IDbEntityBase dbEntityBase)
        {
            if (newState == EntityState.Added)
            {
                dbEntityBase.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Setting property's name as string works. But this code already worked, that's why this is strange to me. Regarding your seconds case, I forgot to mention, I also have some props where I just set "IsModified" property (not current value), but I cannot set that directly on dbEntityBase.

Comment: I don't think using an Interface type instead of an Entity type was ever supposed to work.

Comment: Actually the original code works if `Id` is property of `IDbEntityBase`. Exception is when `Id` is property of another **interface** which `IDbEntityBase` inherits.

Comment: Looks like there's some logic there to handle an interface type, but not enough for all cases.  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/ExpressionExtensions.cs

Comment: @IvanStoev: probably correct, I was refactoring a lot of things and didn't think of it. That was exactly the case in my situation. I think it stopped working, when I moved "Id" property from IDbEntityBase to its parent interface (because of other refactorings). Will do some testing in the near future. Thank you!